# phpmyadmin warning when creating database

Tags: phpmyadmin

Here is my warning

[image: warning]

Is it something important? I don't want to have big problems later because of this warning now, It is appearing when I'm clicking on `new` to create a new database, but I don't get what is it

And after ignoring and creating database (clicking on create)

This warning is coming up
[image: warning2]

Comment: It is informing you that you are using an outdated version of phpMyAdmin, that is calling old, _deprecated_ methods. If creating your table has still succeeded as you intended, then you can ignore those, but it should be updated to a current version nevertheless if possible.

Comment: I finally I ran to a problem, I will now search how to update it, thanks